# \usepackage{tikz} causing "extra }" and "missing }" errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, missing

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this. I am trying to compile my `thesis.tex` file in texstudio (using miktex). Everything works fine and I do not get any errors, until I try to add `\usepackage{tikz}` Then I get the below errors that continue on and on. It says these errors are in the .toc .lot and .lof files, but I cannot find anything wrong in them.

I should also point out that this exact same code works just fine on my wife's computer with the same set-up. She does not get these errors at all. We are both using Windows 10.

```
%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{../library/UNCC-thesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nomencl}


\usepackage{tikz}   %when i comment this out i do not get errors

\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature

\makeatletter

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\fbmatterchapterformat

\doctype{thesis}

%
\title{My lyx thesis}
\author{Test User}
\degree{Master of Science}
\major{Electrical Engineering}
\publicationyear{2015}

\advisor{Dr. Person A}

\committeeMember{Dr. Person B}
\committeeMember{Dr. Person C}


% Generate the preliminary title page and copyright page.
\maketitlepage
\makecopyright
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\begin{dedication}
\end{dedication}
\begin{acknowledgements}

\end{acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents{}

\listoftables


\listoffigures


\newpage
\renewcommand{\nomname}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\settowidth{\nomlabelwidth}{ECE}
\printnomenclature{}

\nomenclature{ECE}{An acronym for Electrical and Computer Engineering.}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
% 2 inch top spacing for new chapters
\bodychapterformat
\begin{preface}

\end{preface}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}


\chapter{CONCLUSIONS}


\fbmatterchapterformat

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references_db}


\newpage{}\uncctocformat{chapter}{0pt}{350pt}{\appendixname~\thecontentslabel:~}
\renewcommand{\chaptertitlename}{APPENDIX}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\appendix


\end{document}
```

I have tried deleting the entire code and starting over, and deleting the .toc .lof and .lot files. I have tried uninstalling texstudio (through the control panel and through texstudio's uninstall option) and miktex and re-installing, I have tried to reconfigure texstudio. I am at a complete loss and have been stuck on this for days.

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}{vii}

Missing } inserted. \contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}{vii}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}{viii}

Missing } inserted. \contentsline {chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}{viii}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...ntsline {chapter}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}{1}

Missing } inserted. ...ntsline {chapter}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}{1}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...e {chapter}{\numberline {1}INTRODUCTION}{2}

Missing } inserted. ...e {chapter}{\numberline {1}INTRODUCTION}{2}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...ion}{\numberline {1.1}Problem Statement}{3}

Missing } inserted. ...ion}{\numberline {1.1}Problem Statement}{3}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...ne {chapter}{\numberline {2}CONCLUSIONS}{5}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @KJO yes, a simple hello world will compile, and also compiles when i add the \usepackage{tikz}. I will try to change the order of the commands.

Comment: Would you agree that it is way more likely that the document class you are using is much more likely to be the culprit? IMHO you should inform the authors.

Comment: @marmot possibly, but I don't understand why it works on other computers and not mine. I just tried the code without any chapters, figures, or tables and it works with the tikz package, but as soon as I add a chapter, figure or table it gives me the errors back. I also logged into a remote computer at school and the code worked fine with everything in it. I have also only been using LaTeX of any kind for a couple months, so I am definitely an amatuer.

Comment: I just downloaded the document class and I reproduce the error, so it is not your computer specifically. The style does a lot of formatting of the table of contents, which may conceivably clash with Ti*k*Z. It is, however, hard to to dig through this. Can you contact the maintainer of this class?

Comment: @marmot thank you. Yes I will try to reach out to them tomorrow.